# Form action redirect to another controller Symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I have a weird problem. I want to setAction to form to redirect to another controller.
I have 2 controllers for user and address. On route /{id}/modify we are in users controller twig and there is this, generated form:

```
        $add=new Address();
    $formAddress=$this->createFormBuilder($add)
        ->setAction($this->redirectToRoute("/{id}/addAddress",array('id'=>$id)))
        ->add("city","text")
        ->add("street","text")
        ->add("housenumber","text")
        ->add("flatnumber","text")
        ->add("send","submit")
        ->getForm();
```

After submitting I want to be redirected to address controller where form will be handled, route of address controller is /{id}/addAddress.
Thanks in advance for answers! Cheers!

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html), you should use `->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route_name', ['id' => $id]))`

Comment: Thanks for help man! Used dozens of variations, this works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action is not correct. If you use the function `redirectToRoute` it expect a route name.

```
// redirect to a route with parameters
return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-page'));
```

The first parameter (string) is the name for the route you try to send your form to. Otherwise you have to use redirect and use `generateUrl` to get the url which does the same but `redirectToUrl` is newer a shorter.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html